# Write a Python program that converts a binary sequence (only 0 and 1) into a decimal integer

Tags: python

Requirements:

1. Define a function decimal(s) that converts s (s is a binary sequence) into decimal integer and return this integer.
2. Ask user to input a binary sequence x which is a sequence of comma separated 4-digit binary numbers and call decimal(x). Display the returned result.

3.The sample output is:

```
Please input a binary sequence (comma separated every 4 digits):10,1011
The decimal integer of 10,1011 is: 43
```

the program I tried to write is:

```
def decimal(s):
    num = s
    dec_value = 0; 


    base1 = 1; 

    len1 = len(num); 
    for x in range(len1 - 1, -1, -1): 
        if (num[x] == '1'):      
            dec_value += base1; 
        base1 = base1 * 2; 

    return dec_value

num=list(input("Please input a binary sequence (comma separated every 4 digits):").split(','))


print("The decimal integer of the number is:", (decimal(num)))
```

The decimal integer comes back as 0 for this example, but should be 43.

Comment: So, what error are you getting, exactly?

Comment: the answer is zero if there have a comma in the binary number

Comment: Hint: You don't disguise your initial question, there is a revision of your previous changes to it.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With minimal changes to your code, you can get it working.

I think the problem is that you've used `split` rather than `replace` on the string:

```
def decimal(s):
    num = s
    dec_value = 0; 


    base1 = 1; 

    len1 = len(num); 
    for x in range(len1 - 1, -1, -1): 
        if (num[x] == '1'):      
            dec_value += base1; 
        base1 = base1 * 2; 

    return dec_value

num=list(input("Please input a binary sequence (comma separated every 4 digits):").replace(',',''))
# only change to code is using .replace instead of .split
print(num)

print("The decimal integer of the number is:", (decimal(num)))
```

split is giving you a list of [10, 1011] (using your example), so the items in the list are ignored by your code (x is never equal to 1 - it's either 10 or 1011, in this case).

replace gives you the list [1,0,1,0,1,1] which works with your function as written.

Comment: Thank you your answering

Comment: @chunglinglam you better click check mark sign at left side of answer rather than comment on it

Answer (score 0):

Try this ( pass a binary string in):

```
def seethat(hm):
  j=1
  for c in range(0, len(hm)):
    if hm[c] == '0':
      j<<=1
    else:
      j = (j<<1)-1
  return j-1
```

```
seethat('10111')                                                                                                                                                                     
# 23

seethat('101011')                                                                                                                                                                    
# 43
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements